# Include depending on body class

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out how to check for a single class on the body tag then include a file.

My `header.php` contains:

```
</head>
<?php $class = BODY_CLASS; ?>
<body class="<?php echo $class; ?>" id="top">
```

And in the body:

```
<?php if (isset($class) && $class == 'work') { ?>
    <?php include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . MODULES . "_social.php"); ?>
<?php }; ?>
```

This works fine so long as I only have a single class on the body tag, but what if I have multiple tags?

for instance my body tag outputs this:

```
<body id="top" class="work project1">
```

How can I check for the `work` even if other classes exist?

Comment: Do you just need the first classname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your if statement a bit and `explode()` your `$class`, by a space to then search in the array for the value with `in_array()`, e.g.

```
if (in_array("work", explode(" ", $class))) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use different approaches, for example, if you are sure that `body` class is always the first word, you can try this

```
$class=current(explode(" ",BODY_CLASS)); //class that you should check
if($class=='')
```

or

```
switch($class) { }
```

which splits the `BODY_CLASS` string and gets the first value.

Anyway, you can also try searching into an array, like this

```
if(in_array('classname',explode(" ",BODY_CLASS)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `explode` together with `in_array`:

`if (isset($class) && in_array('work', explode(' ', $class))) { ...`

References:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php